# Excel 2007 time miliseconds operations

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time

I am using Excel 2007 and I am trying to subtract these two values:

```
11:27:55.428
11:28:09.813
```

I have tried to format both as time and as "hh:mm:ss.000" and every time I try to subtract them I get #VALUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me (Excel 2010). I suspect at least one of your times hasn't been parsed correctly into an Excel datetime.

Try to format your two times to 'General' format (Select them and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>). If they don't then appear as numbers like below, then you have a parsing error - that is Excel isn't interpreting your input as timedates.

```
                hh:mm:ss.000    General
                ------------    -----------
Start time      11:27:55.428    0.477724861
End time        11:28:09.813    0.477891354
Difference      00:00:14.385    0.000166493
```

If you can't get the values to parse correctly when you enter them into the cell you can use the TIME() function to get the right values. For example:

=TIME(11,27,55.428)

Answer (score 0):

I formatted cells A1,A2, and A3 = hh:mm:ss.000

```
A1 = 11:27:55.428
A2 = 11:28:09.813
A3 = A2-A1 = 00:00:14.385
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't like negative date/times, so if you're subtracting the larger from the smaller then the result will not display correctly if time formatted (although you can just show it as General or a Number successfully).

Although, on my system (running 2007) it returns row of hashes instead if `#VALUE`, so this is probably not causing your problem, but worth keeping in mind when performing operations on time values.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, found this working for me.

```
=VALUE(LEFT(B4,8)-LEFT(A4,8))+VALUE((RIGHT(B4,3)/86400000)-(RIGHT(A4,3)/86400000))
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.